# iTextSharp. Why cell background image is rotated 90 degrees clockwise?

Tags: c#, itext

I would like to have cell background using it's natural dimensions and if they don't fit cell - image should be cropped.
One more thing that when I use pattern fill image is actually 90 degress rotated. So the **main thing in this question is why pattern image is rotated after it adding**
I have googled for answer and read documentation, but can't find any explanation.
Here is code:

```
Image img = Image.GetInstance("someImage.png");

var cell = new PdfPCell()
{
    BorderWidthTop = 0,
    BorderWidthBottom = 0,
    BorderWidthLeft = 0,
    BorderWidthRight = 0,
    Padding = 0,
    BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(244, 244, 244),
    BorderColor = new BaseColor(217, 217, 217),
    HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
};
cell.CellEvent = new CellBackgroundEvent() {Image = img};
table.AddCell(cell)
;
```

And here is event handler class:

```
private class CellBackgroundEvent : IPdfPCellEvent
{
    public Image Image { get; set; }

    void IPdfPCellEvent.CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
    {
        PdfContentByte cb = canvases[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];
        PdfPatternPainter patternPainter = cb.CreatePattern(position.Right - position.Left, position.Top - position.Bottom);
        patternPainter.AddImage(Image, position.Right - position.Left, 0, 0, position.Top - position.Bottom, 0, 0);
        cb.SaveState();
        cb.SetPatternFill(patternPainter);
        cb.Rectangle(position.Left, position.Bottom, position.Width, position.Height);
        cb.Fill();
        cb.RestoreState();
    }
}
```

After execution cell background image is rotated 90 degrees clockwise, why?

Image is: [image]

Actual result cell is:

[image]

C# iTextSharp lib version: 5.5.0.0

Comment: I'm puzzled. You scale the background image to fit the cell, and then you fill the background using a pattern? **Why are you doing this?** Furthermore, you have the position of the cell, yet you add *its -background* at the hard-coded coordinates (100, 100). **Why?** I'm sorry, but your code doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, you're right scaling is extra, just removed it. I need to get cell background image - so I use pattern. Hardcoded (100, 100) was actually just for testing myself to see full background image, now is corrected. But general picture is the same - image is rotated 90 degress clockwise and I don't know why and that's why I'm asking for help

Comment: [1.] so you want to use the image as a pattern color (tiled), rather than having the full image as the background of the cell? [2.] I can't reproduce the problem. Can you share the image?

Comment: [1] Right. [2] Yes, sure, added to question details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to achieve something very simple using very complex code. This is what happens when you *code by Google* instead of [*reading the documentation*](http://itextpdf.com/learn)!

Please try this:

```
PdfContentByte cb = canvases[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];
Image.ScaleToFit( position.Top - position.Bottom,position.Right - position.Left);
Image.SetAbsolutePosition(position.Bottom, position.Left);
cb.AddImage(image);
```

Now you are scaling the image to fit the cell and adding it at the coordinate of the lower-left corner of the cell.

**Update 1:**

After having established that you actually want to tile the image, I've written an example trying to reproduce the problem. As I didn't understand your code (*), I had to rewrite large parts of it.

Anyway, you'll find a working Java sample [here](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/TiledBackground). The resulting PDF looks like [this](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/tiled_pattern.pdf) The image isn't rotated, is it? It looks the exact same way as it looks in your question.

This is the relevant code:

```
public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
    try {
        PdfContentByte cb = canvases[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];
        PdfPatternPainter patternPainter = cb.createPattern(image.getScaledWidth(), image.getScaledHeight());
        image.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
        patternPainter.addImage(image);
        cb.saveState();
        cb.setPatternFill(patternPainter);
        cb.rectangle(position.getLeft(), position.getBottom(), position.getWidth(), position.getHeight());
        cb.fill();
        cb.restoreState();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        throw new ExceptionConverter(e);
    }
}
```

(*) Note that you ignored the fact that a `Rectangle` can also give you its width and height. You preferred using the difficult version of the `AddImage()` method. You confused the dimensions of the cell with the dimensions of the image...

**Update 2:**

The Java example was ported to C# (using iTextSharp 5.5.0.0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    public class TiledImageBackground : IPdfPCellEvent {
        protected Image image;

        public TiledImageBackground(Image image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position,
            PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
            PdfContentByte cb = canvases[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];
            PdfPatternPainter patternPainter = cb.CreatePattern(image.ScaledWidth, image.ScaledHeight);
            image.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
            patternPainter.AddImage(image);
            cb.SaveState();
            cb.SetPatternFill(patternPainter);
            cb.Rectangle(position.Left, position.Bottom, position.Width, position.Height);
            cb.Fill();
            cb.RestoreState();
        }
    }


    public class TiledBackground {
        public const String DEST = "results/tables/tiled_pattern.pdf";
        public const String IMG1 = "resources/images/ALxRF.png";
        public const String IMG2 = "resources/images/bulb.gif";

        private static void Main(string[] args) {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Directory.GetParent(DEST).FullName);
            new TiledBackground().CreatePdf(DEST);
        }

        public void CreatePdf(String dest) {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
            Image image = Image.GetInstance(IMG1);
            cell.CellEvent = new TiledImageBackground(image);
            cell.FixedHeight = 770;
            table.AddCell(cell);
            cell = new PdfPCell();
            image = Image.GetInstance(IMG2);
            cell.CellEvent = new TiledImageBackground(image);
            cell.FixedHeight = 770;
            table.AddCell(cell);
            document.Add(table);
            document.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem couldn't be reproduced with this code. In other words: there is no bug in iTextSharp, the functionality was ported correctly.

Please take a moment to try the sample code from this answer to make assure yourself that the error is in your code. If you still have a problem with a changed orientation, you need to take a look at what is different in your code.

**Update 3:**

After an additional comment, we've now established that the 90 degree rotation was intentional. The document was created using:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
```

In this case, you create a document of which the width is smaller than the height (the **MediaBox** is defined as a rectangle in portrait), but you rotate that page (adding a **Rotate** entry equal to 90 to the page dictionary).

If you want the pattern to match the orientation of a page in landscape, you have two options:

- either you rotate the pattern: `img_pattern.setPatternMatrix(0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0);`
- or you create a `MediaBox` in landscape: `new Document(new Rectangle(842, 595));`

Comment: (*) comment: yes, thanks for note, updated description.
One small clarification: I'm using C# iTextSharp lib v.5.5.0.0 and after this code integration it still shows rotated.(see updated question details)

Comment: Normally, the behavior of the C# port should be identical to the behavior of the Java version. I'll make an internal (paid) ticket to check this (low priority, unless you're a paying customer). If you're right, we'll fix it.

Comment: So, you've ported my Java example to C# and you say it behaves differently. What is the orientation of the light bulb from my example? Is it also rotated? http://www.itextpdf.com/img/bulb.gif Please show me the PDF.

Comment: Yes, it behaves differently. Check pdf document [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/86009304/Sample.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for answers, I just want to know whether I missed something in docs or help materials, but looks like it port mismatch and could be currently fixed by additional programmatically rotating pattern source image into 90 degrees counterclockwise.

Comment: OK, I've upgraded the support ticket.

Comment: The problem was tested by support and came back with the message: can not reproduce with the current version of iTextSharp. I'm adding the code of the PoC to my question.

Comment: I found that problem appears when document is created using rotated page with specified page size. So, please use next line:
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A2.Rotate()); 
instead of 
Document document = new Document();
in your code.

Comment: O, but... if we change that behavior, we break existing functionality! People who count on the 90° rotation (because they rotate the page) will suddenly discover that although the page is rotated, the pattern isn't!

Comment: Re: "O, but...":
IMO: It would be nice in iTextSharp to have some field like PageSize.A4.Landscape that would carry on pattern image tying and don't leave people with question "Why cell background image is rotated 90 degrees clockwise?" :)

Comment: At some point in time, we added such page sizes, but they were removed because it was considered *bad design*. It all depends on the point of view. In this case, the point of view to *not* have such constants won.