# Image in mode mosaic in PdfPCell

Tags: itext, itextpdf

I am currently using itextPdf library to generate PDF file.

For to set an image I used [this solution](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/adding-background-table#680-imagebackground.java) of itextpdf.com
Now I want to set a small size image as a background in PdfPCell in mode mosaic : if cell have 3 x ImageSize, in PDF I will have my image repeated 3 times in cell

How I can do it ?

this is my example

```
public class ImageBackgroundEvent implements PdfPCellEvent {

    protected Image image;
    protected boolean mosaic;
    protected boolean full;

    public ImageBackgroundEvent(Image image, boolean mosaic, boolean full) {
        this.image = image;
        this.mosaic = mosaic;
        this.full = full;
    }

    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position,
                           PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        try {
            PdfContentByte cb = canvases[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];
            if(full){
                cell.setImage(image);
            }
            else if(mosaic){
                float imgWidth = image.getWidth();
                float imgHeight = image.getHeight();

                float cellWidth = cell.getWidth();
                float cellHeight = cell.getHeight();

                if(imgHeight < cellHeight && imgWidth < cellWidth){
                    PdfPatternPainter pattern = cb.createPattern(imgWidth, imgHeight);
                    pattern.addImage(image);
                    pattern.setPatternMatrix(-0.5f, 0f, 0f, 0.5f, 0f, 0f);
                    cb.setPatternFill(pattern);
                    //cb.ellipse(180, 408, 450, 534);
                    cb.fillStroke();

                } else{
                    image.scaleAbsolute(position);
                    image.setAbsolutePosition(position.getLeft(), position.getBottom());
                    cb.addImage(image);
                }
            } else{
                image.scaleAbsolute(position);
                image.setAbsolutePosition(position.getLeft(), position.getBottom());
                cb.addImage(image);
            }

        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Bruno, thank for your response. I edited my question. I don't know How I can apply mosaic process.

Comment: I would create a pattern color using the image as one tile in a tiled pattern. I would then apply that pattern color as a background color.

Comment: Have you any example using pattern color with image ?

Comment: A quick search on the official web site, revealed the [TilingPatternColor](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-10#407-tilingpatterncolor.java) example. Doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: I added my code java, I commented ellipse drawing, now I have a problem : I can't set add mosic image in cell

Comment: Why do you always copy/paste code from examples without understanding what the example is supposed to do?

Comment: I have three cases : mosaic, full image size and Image extended in cell. I must do any modification after finish mosaic part

Comment: I have added an answer, and I even updated the answer with a variation. I recognize your name. Didn't you promise to make sure that your employer buys a commercial license for iText once you've proven that iText can do what is needed in your project? Has this happened already? I'm curious to know more about your project.

Comment: Thank you Bruno for your comprehensive explanation

Comment: I will discuss with my employer about your proposition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the [TiledBackgroundColor](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/miscellaneous/pattern-colors#1558-tiledbackgroundcolor.java) example. It takes an image of a light bulb and uses it to define a pattern color:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
Image image = Image.getInstance(IMG);
PdfPatternPainter img_pattern = canvas.createPattern(
        image.getScaledWidth(), image.getScaledHeight());
image.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
img_pattern.addImage(image);
BaseColor color = new PatternColor(img_pattern);
```

Now you can use that color for the background of your cell:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.setFixedHeight(60);
cell.setBackgroundColor(color);
table.addCell(cell);
```

The result looks like this: [tiled_patterncolor.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/tables/cmp_tiled_patterncolor.pdf)

[image]

Or you could add the image in a cell event as shown in the [TiledBackground](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/adding-background-table#1423-tiledbackground.java) example. This example was written in answer to the question [iTextSharp. Why cell background image is rotated 90 degrees clockwise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374557/itextsharp-why-cell-background-image-is-rotated-90-degrees-clockwise)

I've written a variation on this example: [TiledBackgroundColor2](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/miscellaneous/pattern-colors#1560-tiledbackgroundcolor2.java)

The event looks like this:

```
class TiledImageBackground implements PdfPCellEvent {

    protected Image image;

    public TiledImageBackground(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position,
            PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        try {
            PdfContentByte cb = canvases[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];
            image.scaleToFit(10000000, position.getHeight());
            float x = position.getLeft();
            float y = position.getBottom();
            while (x + image.getScaledWidth() < position.getRight()) {
                image.setAbsolutePosition(x, y);
                cb.addImage(image);
                x += image.getScaledWidth();
            }
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(e);
        }
    }

}
```

As you see, I don't care about the actual dimensions of the image. I scale the image in such a way that it fits the height of the cell. I don't use a pattern color either. I just add the image as many time as it fits the width of the cell.

This is how I declare the event to the cell:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
Image image = Image.getInstance(IMG);
cell.setCellEvent(new TiledImageBackground(image));
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Many variations are possible depending on your exact requirement.